# Add a function with multiple return values to SQLite in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, multiple-return-values

I want to add a function to SQLite in Python (like explained [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/438802/))

My function returns multiple values. In python, I can access to different return values by indexing (using `[]`).

However, it seems indexing does not work in SQLite. In other words, the following SELECT statement will have an error:

```sql
SELECT my_function(table1.column1)[0] FROM table1;
```

> sqlite3.OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception

Is there any way to access to different return values in SQLite?

Comment: Apply your index after `fetchall()` rather than in the SELECT query

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for your response. 
Well, I want to create a view and use this function. So, I need to some how apply the index in SELECT query.

Comment: It would be helpful to include your actual code and the traceback as an edit to the question. It's impossible to say for sure what the cause is.

Comment: @roganjosh Unfortunately, I cannot, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to return multiple values from a function is with a [table-valued function](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html#table_valued_functions), which requires creating a virtual table module, which is not possible with only the default Python SQLite driver.

There are additional Python modules to allow this, for example, [sqlite-vtfunc](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/sqlite-table-valued-functions-with-python/).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is to have the function return a string with the multiple values encoded as a JSON array and then use SQLite JSON extraction functions to access the individual values:

```
select json_extract(fout, $[0]) as v0,
       json_extract(fout, $[1]) as v1
from (select my_func(cols...) as fout
      from ...)
```

I have used that solution myself and performance is ok. The JSON encoding/decoding doesn't seem to introduce a noticeable performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks! It's not pretty, or efficient, but it works and it's simple to implement!